# How to inject dependencies into an asmx webservice webmethod?

Tags: c#, asmx

I have an asmx webserice with this method

```
[WebMethod]
double GetBookPrice(int bookID)
{
    //instantiates a DiscountService,DeliveryService and a couple of other services

    //uses various methods of these services to calculate the price
    //e.g. DiscountService.CalculateDiscount(book)

}
```

There are 4 services that are dependencies of this method.

How do now test this method? I will need to inject these dependencies? or should I even do that ? the client is simply sending an int to check the price.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all the `GetBookPrice` method is doing is taking an `int` and passing it along to another method, then returning those results, I'd say testing the service method is of dubious value. It doesn't *hurt* to test it, and it could have value if you want to expand the functionality in the `GetBookPrice` method down the line.

In general, though, if you wanted to test your service, you'd do standard IOC via constructor injection and constructor chaining:

```
public class FooWebService
{
    private readonly ISomeDependency dependency;
    public FooWebService(ISomeDependency dependency)
    {
        //this is what you call during your testing
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }
    public FooWebService() : this(new ConcreteDependencyImplementation())
    {
    }
}
```

When you're testing, you pass in an instance of your dependency (or dependencies!). When you're not testing, the dependency is automatically created and provided by way of calling the parameterless constructor.

Comment: oh so I can just create a service method GetBookPrice(int ID) in the service layer, and just call that from web service. Then I can just test that method....?

Comment: Not quite. I was saying that if your service method is just "passing through" to a different method, you don't need to test the service method, just the method(s) that are doing the heavy lifting.

Comment: Note that this answer does not imply that the ASMX web services support constructor injection via a DI framework (NInject, Autofac, etc.). There is apparently a way to do that but via a lot of effort. An easier solution is to use the technique described in this answer but rather than newing up a concrete dependency you would use the service locator pattern to obtain the services.